# Show that $|G|=240$, $H\leq G$, and $H\cong A_{5}$, then $H\unlhd G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Show that if a group $G$ with order $240$ and $G$ has a subgroup $H$ isomorphic to $A_{5}$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup.

Suppose not, and consider the normalizer of $H$, $N_{G}(H)$. $H\subseteq N_{G}(H)\subsetneq G.$ Note that $H\subsetneq N_{G}(H)$, otherwise $H$ is normal (normalizer is a normal subgroup). Then, $\mid N_{G}(H)\mid = 80$ or $120$. But I cannot go further. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: There are two remarks in your text that make me somewhat uneasy. One is the sentence "normalizer is a normal subgroup". This is generally not the case; instead the normalizer is the largest subgroup in which the subgroup itself is normal. The other issue is your "option" $|N_G(H)|=80$. How is that supposed to happen when $|H|=60$? Are you aware of Lagrange's theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: use the fact that $A_5$ is simple and if $H \leq G$, and $|G:H|=n$, then $G/core_G(H)$ can be embedded homomorphically in $S_n$. (This is sometimes called the $n!$-theorem, proofs can be found all over StackExchange or see [[here]](https://books.google.nl/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), Theorem 1.1). $H \unlhd G$ if and only if $core_G(H):=\bigcap_{g \in G}H^g=H.$ Of course $core_G(H) \subseteq H$, it is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. 
If you understand the proof, you will note that the same holds for $|G|=180$, or $|G|=300$.

Comment: What is $core_G(H)$

Comment: I defined it! It is the kernel of the action of $G$ on the left cosets of $H$ by left multiplication. That sounds complicated but it is not. You also could say: it is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$.

Comment: Ok haha, I didn't know that it had a name.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the associated homomorphism from $G \to S_4$ gotten by acting on the left cosets of $H$ by left multiplication. This already looks suspicious. The kernel of this is certainly non trivial or else you'd have an injective map from a group of order $240$ into one of order $24$.  Moreover, the kernel is contained in $H$ and is thus a normal subgroup of $H$.  However, if it's anything but $H$, then this would imply $A_5$ has a proper non-trivial normal subgroup.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.